# What those two lines mean: o[x] = o[x] || {}; o = o[x];

Tags: javascript, function, namespaces

This is the code I get, but I don't know this two lines means:

```
o[arr[i]] = o[arr[i]] || {};
o = o[arr[i]];
```

Full code:

```
var GLOBAL={};
GLOBAL.namespace=function(str){
    var arr = str.split("."), o=GLOBAL;

    for(i=(arr[0]=="GLOBAL") ? 1 : 0; i<arr.length; i++){
        o[arr[i]] = o[arr[i]] || {};
        o = o[arr[i]];
    }
};

GLOBAL.namespace("A.Dog");
// GLOBAL.A = {};
// GLOBAL.A.Dog = {};
GLOBAL.A.Dog.name = "diudiu";
alert(GLOBAL.A.Dog.name)
```

Comment: first one is the classic `x = x || value`, the second one is just for the loop (think of it as a recursion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break it down step-by-step to make is clearer:

```
o[arr[i]] = o[arr[i]] || {};
```

is the same as:

```
var x = arr[i];
o[x] = o[x] || {};
```

is the same as:

```
var x = arr[i];
if (o[x] == undefined) {
  o[x] = {};
}
```

The pattern `A = B || DEFAULT_VALUE` is an idiom which uses the short-circuiting nature of the `||` operator. In javascript, the `||` operator does not return `true` or `false` but instead it returns the first non-false value or `false`. So if the first variable is not falsy it evaluates to the value of the first variable otherwise it evaluates to the value of the second variable.

Answer (score 3):

There are two statements:

This:

```
o[arr[i]] = o[arr[i]] || {};
```

And:

```
 o = o[arr[i]];
```

The second sets the nested object `o` to its key `arr[i]`, overwriting itself with one of it's own key/values.

The first set's the `o` object's key `arr[i]` to itself or an empty object. The `||` operator is a boolean or and will only trigger the `{}` if `o[arr[i]]` evaluates to false.

This kind of statement is often used to intialize a variable (e.g. in the global namespace) when you don't know if it's already been initialized (so you don't overwrite it).

Comment: `arr[i]`, you're right. tiny type, bad eyes. thanks for catching.

Answer (score 0):

The first line ensures that `o[arr[i]]` is defined. It either sets `o[arr[i]]` to itself if it was previously created, or a new object (i.e. `{}`) if `o[arr[i]]` is undefined.

The second line assigns the object from the first line to `o` so that the namespace traversal can continue.

Answer (score 0):

The function `GLOBAL.namespace(str)` is used to create a namespace (and its sub-namespaces) if it doesn't already exist.

Here is how it works:

- It splits up `str` by periods into sub-namespaces:
  `arr = str.split(".")`
- It sets `o` to the global namespace:
  `o=GLOBAL`
- It skips the first sub-namespace if the first sub-namespace is `GLOBAL`:
  `(arr[0]=="GLOBAL") ? 1 : 0`

For each sub-namespace in `arr`:

- It checks if it exists under `o`, and if it doesn't, it creates it:
  `o[arr[i]] = o[arr[i]] || {};`
- It sets up `o` to work one level deeper, so it can work on the next sub-namespace:
  `o = o[arr[i]];`

For purposes of understanding the function, here's a version with the purpose of each variable spelled out, and steps split up a bit more:

```
var GLOBAL={};
GLOBAL.namespace=function(fullNamespaceName){
  var namespaceNames = fullNamespaceName.split("."); // arr
  var currentNamespace=GLOBAL; // o
  var currentIndex = (namespaceNames[0]=="GLOBAL") ? 1 : 0; // i

  for(; currentIndex<namespaces.length; currentIndex++){
    var subNamespaceName = namespaceNames[currentIndex];
    var subNamespace = currentNamespace[subNamespaceName];
    subNamespace = subNamespace || {};
    currentNamespace[subNamespaceName] = subNamespace;
    currentNamespace = subNamespace;
  }
};
```

Comment: is it a must step to set o = GLOBAL ?

Comment: @user1049555: What would happen if you didn't?  `o` would be null to start with, and the first time through the loop `o[arr[i]] =` would break, since `o` didn't exist beforehand.  You can't set a sub-element of an array if the parent array doesn't exist.  In my more verbose code, you'd still have to, since you can't `currentNamespace[subNamespaceName] =` unless `currentNamespace` exists.